# Why doesn't ":focus:not(:active)" pseudo-class work?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to allow for prevent the styling of the ":focus" pseudo-class from being applying when there is a ":focus:active" or click event without the use of jQuery/JS. As the ":active" state is dependent on the ":focus" state, I would presume that ":focus:not(:active)" work, but it does not. Is there any way to combine ":not" with ":focus" to prevent "focus:active" from triggering "focus"?

Comment: How can something have focus without being active?

Comment: I dont see `:active` anywhere in [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). It is not a selector. Are you assuming that it would be the same as the CSS `:active` selector? I am not sure that is a safe assumption.

Comment: @War10ck a button if previously pressed has focus, but is only active when being pressed down.

Comment: It works for me: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rvvb6ghp/)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Something can not get focused until it is active. So `:focus:not(:active)` is impossible. It can never be triggered.

Comment: An element needs to be activated in order to become focused. However, it can remain focused but be no longer active. In that case, `:focus:not(:active)` works perfectly.

Comment: Both this answer and the comment below it are incorrect. An element can become focused without being active, simply by keyboard tabbing towards the element. It will then have focus applied, yet not be active.

Answer (score 5):

`:not(:focus)` is the closest you can get in CSS

Answer (score 2):

You can juste use [:focus-visible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible) this selector only triggers on focus not on active.

Answer (score 2):

Well... `a:focus:not(:active)` works.

A thing that is important and a bit of a `gotya`, is the order of rules.
Always place the active as last so it overrules the hover.

It might be you want it on a none focus element like div.
Then you would need to add a `tabindex` for the browser to be able to set focus on the div.

And a thing to notice is that you need to assign the rules to a class or a type. A simple `:hover {`  will not work on the div.

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
    * {
        outline: none;
    }

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 3px 8px;
    }

    div {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .magic:focus:not(:active) {
        text-decoration: underline;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 2px 7px;
    }

    .magic:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
        color: green;
    }

    .magic:active {
        text-decoration: line-through;
        color: red;
    }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <a   tabindex="1" class="magic" href="#"> hello </a>
    <div tabindex="2" class="magic" > world </div>
</body>

</html>
```